# IOError [Errno 2] Pickle error in python

Tags: python, pickle

I have a file *analyze.py* where I have :

```
model = joblib.load('svm-model-1.pkl')
```

When I run my python server where *analyze.py* is called, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 443, in load
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file_handle:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/analysis/sleep_apnea_IHR_web_Integration/svm-model-1.pkl'
```

*analyze.py* and *svm-model-1.pkl* are both in the same directory. So, it is not the path issue. Could you tell how to solve this error?

Comment: can you move .pkl file to /tmp directory and update path, check if it works ?

Comment: Go the the machine where this code runs and execute `ls -l /static/analysis/sleep_apnea_IHR_web_Integration/svm-model-1.pkl`
Please make sure the user running the `analyze.py` script has permissions to read the file and that it exists

Comment: _"analyze.py and svm-model-1.pkl are both in the same directory"_ That doesn't matter. The question is if `svm-model-1.pkl` is in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: Yes, the user has permissions to read the file that exists. The error is still there.

Comment: When I moved .pkl file to /tmp dir and updated the path, I am getting " 
    ImportError: No module named numpy_pickle" error.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to use the full path. Either hard code it:

```
model = joblib.load('/path/to/svm-model-1.pkl')
```

or construct it:

```
import os
location = '/the/path'
fullpath = os.path.join(location, 'svm-model-1.pkl')
model = joblib.load(fullpath)
```

If that fails, as commented by immortal you should check the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Pickel should help easily:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
file=open("file","wb")
import pickle
pickle.dump(a,file)
file.close()
file=open("file","rb")
b=pickle.load(file)
file.close()
print(b)
```

will print give result as

```
[1,2,3,4]
```